# Error installing cartalyst/sentinel

Tags: git, laravel-4, composer-php, cartalyst-sentinel

When i am trying to install sentinel with composer

```
"repositories": 
    [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.cartalyst.com"
    }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "cartalyst/sentinel": "1.0.*"
    },
```

composer update

i get the following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing cartalyst/support (v1.1.1)
    Downloading: connection...    Failed to download cartalyst/support from dist
: The "https://api.github.com/repos/cartalyst/support/zipball/1ba474441bc0d8579e
76d2eed67013f66dd97006" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing cartalyst/support (v1.1.1)
    Cloning 1ba474441bc0d8579e76d2eed67013f66dd97006



  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout "https://c81076146cfe987b80b6d1c3
  3f0c832271abd586:***@github.com/cartalyst/support.git" "C:\Users\Max\Dropbo
  x\Projects\Libeari-dev\vendor\cartalyst\support" && cd /D "C:\Users\Max\Dro
  pbox\Projects\Libeari-dev\vendor\cartalyst\support" && git remote add compo
  ser "https://:***@github.com/cartal
  yst/support.git" && git fetch composer
  Cloning into 'C:\Users\Max\Dropbox\Projects\Libeari-dev\vendor\cartalyst\su
  pport'...
  remote: Repository not found.
  fatal: repository 'https://:x-oauth
  -basic@github.com/cartalyst/support.git/' not found
```

I've tried reinstalling composer, starting a a fresh project, nothing works?

Comment: serverfault, not stackoverflow.

Comment: @MarcusMüller nosense, it's about installing a PHP (which is a programming language) package. That's perfectly on topic for SO and would be very off-topic for ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cartalyst Sentinel is a paid package where as Cartalyst Sentry is the free downscaled version of the Authorization Package. You'll need to pay $75 to get access via Github.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most important clue (the last lines, ironically):

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://:x-oauth-basic@github.com/cartalyst/support.git/' not found
```

Now, looking at http://github.com/cartalyst/support.git you can see that it indeed does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Sentinel you need a subscription: on the top of the page https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel, says: This package requires a valid subscription. Subscribe for access.

Answer (score 0):

You need a subscription and after go to

> Github profile -> Settings -> SSH KEYS -> Add SSH Key

Go to your machine and grab your user ssh key.